# Как запретить биндить символ знака вопроса в SQL-запросе при использовании PDO в PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

В SQL-запросе используется символ знака вопроса - `?` и PDO пытается биндить к нему значение `($1)`, но в данной ситуации это совершенного не нужно, т.к. символ знака вопроса это оператор языка SQL для работы с типом данных `JSONB`. Как обойти этот механизм присвоения значений?

```
$statement = "SELECT id FROM public.parameter WHERE variations ?| array[ 'something' ] LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;";
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare( $statement );
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Обратным слешем не экранируется?

Comment: Нет, не экранируется.

Comment: Я нагуглил [вот этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30464989/2076787) на английском SO как раз про ваш случай. Если он вам поможет, можете отблагодарить сообщество, переведя этот ответ на русский язык и опубликовав его сюда, ответом. Если с переводом проблемы, могу заняться сам.

Comment: Напишите сами ответ, а я отмечу его как решение. Хотя это костыль! И это не тру... Но это работает...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Вместо таких операторов можно использовать соответствующие функции
>   (`jsonb_exists`, `jsonb_exists_any`, `jsonb_exists_all`).
>
> К примеру, если запустить в `psql` команду `\do+ "?"`, выведется имя функции,
>   которая вызывается оператором `?`.
>
> А можно определить собственный оператор без символов `?`, например:
>
> ```
> CREATE OPERATOR ~@ (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text, PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists)    
> CREATE OPERATOR ~@| (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any)
> CREATE OPERATOR ~@& (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_all)
> ```
>
> ...чтобы использовать `~@`, `~@|` и `~@&` вместо `?`, `?|` и `?&`
>   соответственно. Пример:
>
> ```
> $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE meta ~@ :value");
> $sth->bindValue(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
> $sth->execute();
> ```

Это перевод [вот этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464989/2076787) с английского StackOverflow от пользователя [**alexius**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171262/alexius).

Answer (score 1):

Для решения этой ситуации на [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461558/jsonb-existential-operators-with-parameterised-queries/30464989#30464989) предлагают создать свои собственные операторы без символа ? и выглядит это вот так:

```
-- Because PHP::PDO replace symbol '?' into SQL-query we can not use this operator for work with JSONB type.

-- alternative operator for '?'
CREATE OPERATOR ~@ (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text, PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists);

-- alternative operator for '?|'
CREATE OPERATOR ~@| (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any);

-- alternative operator for '?&'
CREATE OPERATOR ~@& (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_all);
```

Теперь мною приведенный выше PHP-код стал рабочим (разумеется я заменил оператор `?|` на `~@|`

```
$statement = "SELECT id FROM public.parameter WHERE variations ~@| array[ '" . mb_strtolower( $title ) . "' ] LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;";
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare( $statement );
$sth->execute();
```

Но, друзья, это ведь костыль!